# Is it better to store some database refrence data in the node key or as a value?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a timeline node as seen bellow. I first store the uid of the user who follows some users who have made posts. Then I store the posterUID and the postID right next to it with a ':' separating the info so i can easily get each part later. Then I store the timeStamp of the post.

```
"Post_Timeline" : {
    "uid" : {
      "posterUID:postID" : {//example postID value: "post:583190375"
        "timeStamp" : 583190375
      },
```

I wonder if it would be more efficient to do something like (by efficient I mean quicker to fetch or get the right info. Or maybe in terms of firebase cost. ect.):

```
"Post_Timeline" : {
    "uid" : {
      "randomID" : {
        "timeStamp" : 583190375,
        "posterUID" : "JNFSD78436VSFFDSF"
      },
```

The code I use to fetch:

```
ref.child("Timeline").child((Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!)
            .queryOrdered(byChild: "timeStamp")
            .queryLimited(toLast: 10)
            .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

                var i = 0
                for case let rest as DataSnapshot in snapshot.children.reversed() {//.reversed()
                    let keyValue = rest.key
                    let uid = keyValue.split(separator: ":")[0]
                    let postIDDoubleVal = keyValue.split(separator: ":")[2]

                    self.fetchUsersPost(uid: "\(uid)", postID: "post:\(postIDDoubleVal)")
```

I use this timeline to get the 10 most recent posts created by users whom the current user follows.

Comment: Can you explain what is 'postID' in 'posterUID:postID'? Is it the push key firebase generates or is it a custom one?

Comment: One data structure is not more efficient than another, as they're both just data structures. It only once you consider use-cases that you can start seeing differences in performance. Without seeing a very specific use-case (and code), it's going to be hard to give a concrete answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, Firebase structures are dependent on the types of queries you're going to use. IMO it's often times best practice to disassociate node keys from the data they contain - especially if the node key could possibly be dynamic data like an email or user name that could possibly change in the future.

I will pose this answer by providing examples of why

```
"posterUID:postID"
```

could be bad.

It goes without saying that you obviously have to have code to encode/decode node keys so that's just additional code.

*Issue #1:* What if the same user posts twice to a post?

```
uid
   posterUID:postID
      timeStamp: 583190375
   posterUID:postID
      timeStamp: 123456789
```

Ah - can't do that as you cannot have duplicate keys within the same node

*Issue #2:* Any kind of queries about a specific post can't be done without reading in all of the nodes and filtering in code. That could be a lot of data or a lot of redundancy

*Issue #3:* Getting all of the times posts were made about a specific post from any user being followed. Firebase doesn't support partial *ending* string queries.

*Issue #4:* Post_1234 was deleted and now I need to delete references to that node from the "uid" node. Well, that's not going to happen without reading in all of the child nodes.

There are a number of additional issues that *may* be encountered but those cannot be addressed without understanding the full scope of what queries may be run.

This appears to be a more flexible solution

```
Post_Timeline
   uid
      randomID
        timeStamp: 583190375,
        posterUID: "JNFSD78436VSFFDSF"
```